# Adding Sliding Effect to Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a javascript counter which looks something like this towards the output.

```
out=
                "<div id='days'><span>"+ days +"</span></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours'><span>" + hours +"</span><</div>" + 
                "<div id='mins'><span>" + mins +"</span></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs'><span>" + secs +"</span></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;


                setTimeout("GetCount()", 1000);
```

I was wondering what the method would be to use some jQuery for effects such as `.fadeOut()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To animate the numbers, you can wrap `countbox`'s children in jQuery and call the animation, similar to what Joao said:

`$('#countbox').children().fadeout();`

and put this in your `GetCount()` method.

Edit:

To get the individual numbers (and corrected animation method):

`$('#countbox div').children().fadeOut();`

Edit #2:

I added this to get what I believe is your desired effect:

`var x = setInterval(function(){$('#countbox div').children().fadeOut()}, 1000);`

and each number fades out after it appears.

Comment: I've tried both methods, and I can't effect the individual numbers are they are updated. Adding `$('#countbox').children().fadeout();` to my `GetCount()` method doesn't have any effect that I can see. Here is my live script. jako.in/countdown

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `countbox` in a jQuery object and call any animation function:

```
$("#countbox").fadeOut();
```

Comment: I was able to get that working, but doing so effects the entire countbox div, rather than the specific numbers that are counting down.

Comment: You can select a specific div with `$("#countbox div#days")`.

Comment: I've tried both methods, and I can't effect the individual numbers are they are updated. Here is my live script. http://jako.in/countdown/

Comment: @Jako: But what exactly do you want to do?